# How can i play music in webview?

Tags: android, html, object, webview

the code is this:

```
<audio id="audio" src="test.mp3" autoplay="autoplay">the browser can't play</audio>
```

The audio is html5 tag and supports only ogg, mp3 and wvm but my file is amr or other format.

Also the code is written for tablet or phone, not for PC

Can i use  tag and appoint `classid` to play it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Streaming Audio with Rackspace CDN</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    <audio controls>
    <source src="http://81310752d5730fb4ef3c-221b4998ec12974102282b6d4a8fafbe.r2.cf1.rackcdn.com/3rds.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="http://81310752d5730fb4ef3c-221b4998ec12974102282b6d4a8fafbe.r2.cf1.rackcdn.com/3rds.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio.</em>
    </audio>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```